# Why is javascript unable to get asp:Label innerText?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I have two labels: username and email. I use them to retrieve their content and pass them as method parameters.

```
var lblEmail = $get('<%= lblEmail.ClientID %>');
var email = lblEmail.innerText;

var lblUsername = '<%= lblUsername.ClientID %>';
var username = lblUsername.innerText;
```

The email label is defined in the same way as username label does, but for this last I can't get the value, innertext returns undefined.

...

```
<td class="inputField">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<asp:Label ID="lblUsername" CssClass="font1" runat="server"/>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
```

...

```
...
<td class="inputField">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEmail" CssClass="font1" />
</td>
...
```

What could be a possible reason to justify what is happening? How can I solve this problem? I'm seeing on the page both label values, I set them on the same place (when page loads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you defined only the client ID for the userName label :

```
var lblEmail = $get('<%= lblEmail.ClientID %>');
var email = lblEmail.innerText;

var lblUsername = '<%= lblUsername.ClientID %>';
var username = lblUsername.innerText;
```

Comment: OMG, what a shame! I didn't see it before :P It was clear aahaha, thanks dude!

Comment: sometimes it happens, take a break :)

Comment: I'm confused are you trying to show the proper code or just copying his code over again?

Comment: yes, I copied the problematic part. it's obvious, no need to correct it I think.

Comment: innerHTML will work on other browsers, but will include any HTML embedded within the label.

Answer (score 5):

In the second part of your code

```
var lblEmail = $get('<%= lblEmail.ClientID %>');
var email = lblEmail.innerText;

var lblUsername = '<%= lblUsername.ClientID %>';
var username = lblUsername.innerText;
```

**$get** call is absent. Should be

```
var lblEmail = $get('<%= lblEmail.ClientID %>');
var email = lblEmail.innerText;

var lblUsername = $get('<%= lblUsername.ClientID %>');
var username = lblUsername.innerText;
```